# Get @Rule to Build Before Global Variables in Kotlin JUnit5 Testing

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, kotlin

Is it possible to get the @Rule to Build before any declared Global Variables?
I tried:

```
@Rule 
@Before // This Causes an Error
val rule = SomeAndroidComposeTestRule()

private val globalVariable = GlobalVariableClass()
```

I need the rule to run first because I am getting an error that the Composable I am testing using that globalVariable needs the test rule. When I debug theres all sorts of errors. Is there an @ that will allow the @Rule to be ran first?

Answer (score 1):

If those five lines in your code snippet are five contiguous lines from your test class, then `globalVariable` is not a global variable. It is a property of your test class.

Regardless, there is no way to force some `@Rule` to execute before a property initializer. Hence, you need to delay initialization, such as into a `@Before`-annotated function:

```kotlin
@Rule 
val rule = SomeAndroidComposeTestRule()

private lateinit var globalVariable: GlobalVariableClass

@Before
fun setUp() {
  globalVariable = GlobalVariableClass()
}
```